# Android webview layout - when to set position?

Tags: android, layout, view

I have the following XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout android:id="@+id/rl"
    android:background="@color/red"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <WebView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/webview"
        android:layout_width="10dp"
        android:layout_height="10dp" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

When I call:

```
view.layout(50, 50, 1024 - 50, 600 - 50);
```

from onCreate() and onStart(), it has no effect. But when I add the same call to shouldOverrideKeyEvent() and press a key, it works. I think it's because my settings are being overriden by XML's ones. So, the question is: when should I call layout() as soon as possible, but after android:layout_width="10dp" and android:layout_height="10dp" are already applied.

**UPDATE**

I use the solution by blessenm.

```
private class LayoutListener implements OnGlobalLayoutListener
{
    public void onGlobalLayout()
    {
        Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
        int screenWidth = display.getWidth();
        int screenHeight = display.getHeight();

        // Workaround for a 'fill_parent' bug on my tablet (Kindle Fire).
        _WebView.layout(0, 0, screenWidth, screenHeight);
        _WebView.loadUrl("http://192.168.1.2");
        //_Layout.getViewTreeObserver().removeGlobalOnLayoutListener(this); 
    }
}
```

If I comment removeGlobalOnLayoutListener() out, it stops working. Debugger shows it's called twice, so I guess the second call only actually sets the size. So, I've decided not to remove the listener (if it's called 2 times, that's not a performance killer). It'd seemed OK, until I realized it's called whenever I click a permanent bottom-bar, causing toolbar appearance. And since I load a site after setting layout, it's being reloaded every time. And I have to load the site only when the view' size is correct, because a server sends content, specially optimized for the given size.

That's why I cannot leave the listener and should remove it. But when? Just count to 2? Will it work on every device/Android version? Why does it work for the second call, but not for the first?

Regards,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think its because in the onCreate event the layouts haven't been drawn or measured yet. So If you try to call layout in that event it wont have an impact. Try to put your code in the viewtreeobserver, it might work.

Add this to your activity's onCreate

```
ViewTreeObserver vto        =   layout.getViewTreeObserver(); 
    vto.addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new OnGlobalLayoutListener() { 
    @Override 
    public void onGlobalLayout() { 
        view.layout(50, 50, 1024 - 50, 600 - 50);
        layout.getViewTreeObserver().removeGlobalOnLayoutListener(this); 
    } 
});
```

where layout can be your parent or outer layout.

Comment: Thank you. It seems like there are 2 errors in your code. 1. (Obvious one) The listener is interface, not class, you have to implement onGlobalLayout(), not override it. The annotation is unneeded. 2. I don't know why, but one call of onGlobalLayout() is not enough. If you remove the instance, it stops to work. I'll try to find how frequently it's called to decide, should I remove it at all. (And if I should then, maybe, when left/top/right/bottom are already what I want, not immediately).

Comment: It's called twice only. I think it's OK to leave the listener.

Comment: No, leaving causes a problem. Please see UPDATE section.

Comment: At the moment I think you are going to need to use your count method. ViewTreeObserver gets called whenever there is a change to the UI like redraws or adding or removing layouts.

Answer (score 4):

```
WebView webview = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.webview);
MarginLayoutParams marginsParams = new MarginLayoutParams(webview.getLayoutParams());
marginsParams.setMargins(50, 50,1024-50, 600-50);
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lp = new LayoutParams(marginsParams);
webview.setLayoutParams(lp);
```

try this code::::

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't understand how to deal with the layout params. I tried the code in onCreate, to no avail.

Comment: Yep, I do layout from OnGlobalLayoutListener, it works. See blessenm's answer for details.